# Finding $n$ disjoint paths in a graph which minimize number of vertices.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms

Let $G$ be a graph and fix $A,B$ two vertices. I want to find $n$ disjoint paths $P_1,...,P_n$ from $A$ to $B$ such that the total number of vertices $\# V(\cup_{i=1}^n P_i)$ is minimized. Disjoint here means for $i\neq j$, the vertex set only intersects at $A,B$, meaning $V(P_i)\cap V(P_j)=\{A,B\}$.

The first question concerns the that of existence. Is there any way to guarantee the existence of $n$ disjoint paths that satisfy this constraint?

The second concerns finding an explicit algorithm that finds $P_1,...,P_n$. I originally proposed the algorithm of finding the paths "one at a time". Namely take a path $P_1$ which minimizes the number of vertices in $P_1$, then take $P_2$ a path which minimizes vertices in $G-P_1$ (take out the path $P_1$ except of course $A,B$), etc. However, it's easy to construct a counterexample showing this algorithm this doesn't work. I can give more details if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 2):

The graphs which admits $n$ disjoint A-B paths can be characterized by the Menger theorem, which state that these graphs must not have a A-B vertex cut of size less than $n-1$.

$n$ disjoint paths can be found in polynomial time by converting the problem to a max flow problem. If your original graph is undirected, replace every edge by two arcs of opposite directions. We set the vertex $A$ as a source vertex, and $B$ as a sink vertex. We duplicate every other vertex $v$ in two vertices $v_{in}$ and $v_{out}$. We add an edge from $v_{in}$ to $v_{out}$. Arcs leading toward $v$ are replaced by arcs leading toward $v_{in}$ and arcs leaving $v$ are replaced by arcs leaving $v_{out}$. Set a capacity of $1$ on every arc.

Run a max flow algorithm. The flows obtained must be all integers ($0$ or $1$).
You will have $n$ disjoint edges if you find a max flow of weight $n$. The disjoint paths are given by the edges with a flow of $1$.

You can minimize the total length of the paths in polynomial time by adding a cost of $1$ on each edge between an "in" and an "out" vertex and solving the corresponding minimum cost maximal flow problem.

Apparently, [there is a specialized algorithm if $n=2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suurballe%27s_algorithm), I don't know if it is the case for a general $n$.

There are also specialized algorithms for finding disjoint paths, but these are probably not minimizing the total length of the paths:
*Grossi, Roberto; Marino, Andrea; Versari, Luca*, [**Efficient algorithms for listing (k) disjoint (st)-paths in graphs**](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-77404-6_40), Bender, Michael A. (ed.) et al., Latin 2018: theoretical informatics. 13th Latin American symposium, Buenos Aires, Argentina, April 16–19, 2018. Proceedings. Cham: Springer. Lect. Notes Comput. Sci. 10807, 544-557 (2018). [ZBL1485.68184](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1485.68184).